# Reading input chars from single line of a file

Tags: c++, inputstream

So my task is to read a line from a file
example:

```
4. 7 3-+ 2 -3+
```

and feed this into a string variable one by one.

One issue is there are 0 or more white spaces between numbers and symbols , but there is atleast 1 whitespace between one number and another. So how can I differentiate each number/symbol?

Comment: Cut all whitespaces off and read it in. Or change the position of the reader by +1 if a whitespace is there.

Comment: The [`<cctype>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cctype) header has things like `isalpha`, `isdigit`, etc, that may help here. If you need proper localization, you can get basically the same things with `C++` locales.

Comment: what if the number is of double format? Wouldnt that be an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you read the entire line through getline(), then parse the string character-wise and maybe build another string.

```
cin.getline( myString );
for ( int i = 0; i < myString.size(); i++ ) {
  if ( myString[i] != ' ' ) {

    if ( myString[i] >= '0' && myString[i] <= '9' {
      // do something with numbers;
    } else {
      // do something with characters.
    }

  }
}
```

Other option is to read character by character. These solutions shall work only with single digit numbers. For more than one digits you will have to again build the number character by character.

```
char ch;
cin >> std::noskipws; // needed to recognize the end of line character.
while ( cin >> ch && ch != '\n' ) {
  if ( ch != ' ' ) {

    if ( ch >= '0' && ch <= '9' {
      // do something with numbers;
    } else {
      // do something with characters.
    }

  }
}
cin >> std::skipws;
```

Comment: I think this is exactly what i was looking for. Thank You! Just one question. Lets say i was to put all these into a vector 1 by 1, then how would i insert a number like 4.5 into just one block in the vector?

Comment: Of course, this means that his final `-3` will be parsed as a sign, followed by a number.  And that the numbers will be just a single digit.  I'd thought about roughly the same thing (but using `getline`, then `>>` on a `istringstream`, which would automatically skip the blanks), but found that I needed more than one character look-ahead.

Comment: @user3115535 You will need to parse the number character by character. For example if you encounter 4, you will need to keep track of future characters till you keep getting either a '.' or more numbers.

Comment: @JamesKanze Yes so a '-' sign shall be treated as a possible 'more than one digit number'. Also, if stringstream is used, then the relative order of numbers and characters are not tracked.

Comment: This assignment doesnt include negatives so im a bit lucky on that part, so i managed to get the whole line into a vector, now i can keep track of the next index.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal Of course they are.  There's no difference between using a `istringstream` and reading directly from the input.  My hope in using the `istringstream` was to be able to input the numbers directly, letting the `istringstream` determine where the number ended.  Otherwise, there's no advantage in reading anything but lines, and iterating over the characters in the classic fashion.

Comment: @user3115535 Depending on what you're doing after, it's quite possible to treat something like `-3` as a unary minus operator followed by the number `3`.  (This is how C++ is defined.  There are no negative integer literals.)

Comment: @JamesKanze for an input of '3-+ 2', wouldn't istringstream  store the numbers and characters as (3,2) and (-,+). How can we decipher that the characters were between the numbers?

Comment: @AbhishekBansal The istringstream doesn't store anything except the original line.  For an input of `3-+2`, you would use four extractions: the first to a number (`double`) the second and third to a `char`, and the last to a number.  You choose which extractor to use by looking at the next non-white space: if it is a digit, extract to a number, otherwise to a char.  Or extract systematically to a char; if it is a digit, unget and extract to a number.  (As already mentionned, this only works if you don't have to input negative numbers.)

Comment: @JamesKanze Yes what I mean is that to decipher the type of next non-white space, you will have to first extract it as a 'char'.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you can read whole line into string with `getline()`. Now string supports `find_first_of()` and `find_first_not_of()`, which allows to effectively read until whitespace and then skip it.

Not tested:

```
string delims = " \t"
getline(file, line);
int tokenStart, tokenEnd = 0;
string token;
tokenStart = line.find_first_not_of(delims, tokenEnd);
tokenEnd = line.find_first_of(delims, tokenStart);
// substr expects length, not end of substring
token = line.substr(tokenStart, tokenEnd-tokenStart);
```